# value is undefined for some users, empty string for others

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that on submission packages the data into an ajax format and sends to a coldfusion script via ajax. A bug crept up that affected from two computers but not mine and another.  I tracked it down to a struct key not existing.  When I do a console log of the packaged json data, we all see the struct key before it's passed. For me, its value is an empty string. For others, it says undefined. And because of that, coldfusion appears to drop the key from the struct after receiving it, which is what caused the initial issue we had. Once that was determined it was a simple fix.

The struct key is assigned a value from a jquery object, which is a SELECT element (no multiple). My structure would look something like this:

```
var fields = {
    myVar: $('#import_me').val()
};
```

What I'm trying to figure out is why, when nothing is selected, does it assign an empty string for me but will be undefined for my colleagues?  We're on the same browser and version.

Would this give me more consistent results instead?

```
$('#import_me option:selected').val()
```

Comment: The value of a select element defaults to the first option, if any option is not selected. Maybe the element (or options in it) doesn't exist at the time it's retrieved? It's easy to check with native JS, it'll throw an error, if the element won't exist.

Comment: Is the script tag which loads the js above the body tag in your page HTML?

Comment: `.val()` returns `null`, if there's no options, if the select element is not found, the result is `undefined`. The empty string can be a result only in the case the value of the selected option is the empty string. Are you sure you're not overriding the value read from the select somewhere later?

Comment: In the SELECT, nothing is explicitly checked but the first option does have a value set to an empty string.  Which be default, is what I expect to be returned. I'm just confused why I get the empty string and others get undefined.  @Rahul, the above code is in a function which is called when the save button is clicked in the form. (The click event action is assigned in the $(document).ready function)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

A fallback:

```
var fields = {
    myVar: $('#import_me').val() || ''
};
```

It should set an empty string as fallback if there is no val()

But possibly this is better:

Check the variable and set it to empty string if it is undefined.

```
var fields = {
    myVar: $('#import_me').val()
};

if (fields[myVar] === undefined) {
    fields[myVar] = "";
}
```